# Does Spring Cloud Stream support RabbitMQ Stomp over Websocket

Tags: java, spring, event-driven, spring-cloud-stream

I'm using **Spring Cloud Stream** (SpringBoot) to communicate with **RabbitMQ** instance.

The project could connect to RabbitMQ through **AMQP**, but **not work** for **STOMP**. Anyone knows: is stomp supported or not and how to configure? (My RabbitMQ has opened the 61613 port)

The **application.yml** file is like this:

```
server:
  port: 8080
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        output:
          destination: cloud-stream
  rabbitmq:
    addresses: amqp://192.168.231.130:5672 # this works
    #addresses: stomp://192.168.231.130:61613 # this does not work
    username: test
    password: test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

STOMP is not currently a supported binder protocol.

Comment: Thank you @Gary Russell. Is there any plan for stomp binder and other MQ brokers, such as ActiveMQ, ZeroMQ...